# how to filter objects to get the sum of the repeated values in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

models.py

```
name = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
date = models.DateTimeField()
orders = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

this is the model which counts daily orders of a user. the order which is made in the same day will just increase the orders count by one.

So how to make a query or serializer which gives the result of users with their total orders of all time

eg:

```
 [{name:albert, orders:35},
{name:Vncent, orders:35},
{name:john, orders:35},
{name:dion, orders:35},
{name:aoidi, orders:35},]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. It'll actually group by the name and sum the orders. the total column name will be `total_orders`. I assume that your model is `Customer`

```
from django.db.models import Sum

customers = Customer.objects.values('name').annotate(total_orders=Sum('orders'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count,Sum
```

if you want total sum of orders you can use this:

```
Shop.objects.values("date__date","name").annotate(daily_count=Sum("orders"))
```

or if you want +1 for every instance of Model for the same date:

```
Shop.objects.values("date__date", "name").annotate(daily_count=Count("orders"))
```

**Update:**
This will return counts as per Days instead total. You can remove `date__date` from values if you want all the counts without datetime filter as per @BairavanD's answer.